# how to insert text in matching line only and only if not already present for bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Trying to search /etc/pam.d/common-password file for entry that starts with password    required   pam_unix.so and check to see if sha512 is in the fourth column.  If its there, do nothing.  If its not there add it.  It could be anywhere in the fourth column, but it seems easiest to add to the end if not there.

```
password        required        pam_unix.so     use_authtok nullok shadow try_first_pass
```

So ending line should look like:

```
password        required        pam_unix.so     use_authtok nullok shadow try_first_pass sha512
```

Using the below if statement and replacing the comment with my command:

```
if [[ "$(grep  'password'$'\t''required'$'\t''pam_unix.so' common-password | cut -f4)" != *"sha512"* ]]; then
    >&2 echo 'Remediation needs to be done'
fi
```

Tried below awk but end up with an empty common-password file

`awk '/^'password'$'\t''required'$'\t''pam_unix.so'/{print $0," sha512"}' /etc/pam.d/common-password > /etc/pam.d/common-password.fixed && mv /etc/pam.d/common-password.fixed /etc/pam.d/common-password`

Tried below grep and sed, but get error "sed: no input files"

`grep -F 'password'$'\t''required'$'\t''pam_unix.so' /etc/pam.d/common-password | sed --follow-symlinks -ie 's/$/& sha512/g'`

Need to be able to find this line and modify it and only this line.  And only if it has not already been modified.  I only want to modify this one line if it exists and leave the rest of the file intact.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, try to avoid pipelines of regex processors when one will do the job of all of them. All it costs is processes, memory, and cpu cycles, which is no big deal for small, off-the-cuff tasks, but you'll benefit in the long run from the few extra seconds of thinking how to clean it up, and on BIG tasks it can make a considerable difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `gnu-awk` you can make use of `-i inplace` and set the field separator and the output field separator to a tab to compare the field values.

Then you can check if field 4 does not contain sha512 using `$4 !~ /sha512/`

For example

```
awk -i inplace '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
$1=="password" && $2=="required" &&  $3=="pam_unix.so" &&  $4 !~ /sha512/{$0 = $0 OFS "sha512"}1
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

For one line, use `vi` and save yourself the trouble of fixing the mess a typo will make.

If you really need an automated edit, simplify to one executable and consolidate your logic.

```
$: sed -i '/password\trequired\tpam_unix.so\t/{ /\tsha512/{n}; s/$/\tsha512/; }' file
```

this:

1. searches for records that have the initial required string of `password\trequired\tpam_unix.so\t`
2. opens a block that groups statements to be executed collectively in `{...}`
3. searches for records to *exclude* with `/\tsha512/{n}`; the `n` goes on to the `next` record and skips the rest of the steps in the outer block. This *will* still output the record, so it won't be deleted from the file on the in-place edit (use `d` for that).
4. if the previous check did not match, the `n` won't be executed, so the next command `s`ubstitutes in the string you want at the end of the record.
5. the closing brace of the outer block ends the set of commands on the only outer scan, so `sed` proceeds to the next record.

If the end-of-record tab logic is not an issue, and you are sure there are no trailing tabs otherwise, or if you are confident that they indicate an empty final field, just use `'s/$/\tsha512/'`, but if it's possible there might be *trash* tabs at the end of the record, you might want to clean those - maybe `'s/\t*$/\tsha512/'`, or even `'s/\t{0,1}$/\tsha512/'`. Check your file and your logic against the possible consequences of carelessly editing...

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  I was clearly making it way more difficult then it needed to be.  I do need to automate because I have to run this on over 100 servers.  I made a few changes.  Added --follow-symlinks since common-password is a symbolic link and also modified the sha512 to replace the tab with a space.  The entries in column four are all in column 4 separated with a space.  THANKS AGAIN

Comment: so final line of code looks like this: sed --follow-symlinks -i '/password\trequired\tpam_unix.so\t/{ / sha512/{n}; s/$/ sha512/; }' /etc/pam.d/common-password